# How to stop bootchart?

Tags: bootchart

Bootchart set up png file every time machine starting.
How to make bootchart nor working without remove it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bootchart service is started using Upstart init scripts, so you can disable it in the usually manner...

```
echo manual | sudo tee -a /etc/init/bootchart.override
```

Remove the file if you want to restart it.